# Perl Regular Expression Not Working

Tags: regex, perl

Can you tell me why this:

```
($revID, $who, $date, $nlines) =~ m/(\w+) \| (\w+) \| ([0-9-]*) .*\| ([0-9]*) line/;
```

doesn't match this:

**r36043 | cmiuch | 2014-10-01 10:51:01 -0400 (Wed, 01 Oct 2014) | 1 line**

revID, who, date all come out as empty.

Comment: Would it not be simpler to `split` on `|`?

Comment: Possibly - I wanted to drop the second portion of the date (time and offset, etc.) and the " line" at the end to get just the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the regex against the variable where the actual input is stored. ie, `$var =~ m//;`

```
my $var = "r36043 | cmiuch | 2014-10-01 10:51:01 -0400 (Wed, 01 Oct 2014) | 1 line";
my ($revID, $who, $date, $nlines) = $var =~ m/(\w+) \| (\w+) \| ([0-9-]+) .*\| ([0-9]+) line/;
print $revID."\n".$who."\n".$date."\n".$nlines."\n";
```

**Output:**

```
r36043
cmiuch
2014-10-01
1
```

Comment: The way he wrote it should work with `$_`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Barmar Of course not. If he had used `=`, then yes.

Comment: It looks like the basic error he made was to use `=~` when he meant `=` -- he probably intended to use `$_` by default.

Comment: Yes - I thought =~ would apply to $_ by default - basic mistake.  Thanks!